# Is OrientDB document-database? or graph-database?

Tags: database, document-databases, graph-databases

Some document says [OrientDB](http://www.orientechnologies.com/orient-db.htm) is document-database, some others talks it's graph-database. What's right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's both: internally manages relationships like GraphDB but can work in schema-less mode like DocumentDB. So both.

Answer (score 3):

According to a conversation with Luca Garulli, OrientDB creator, it is both a document and graph database. The complete discussion is available here providing more details on how OrientDB operates internally: http://nosql.mypopescu.com/post/1254869909/correction-orientdb-is-a-document-and-graph-store

Answer (score 0):

Orient DB is Document-Graph (and/or) DBMS. According to [the comparison with MongoDB](http://www.orientdb.org/orientdb_vs_mongodb.htm), OrientDB can store data as JSON type documents but with one (out of many) added benefit of keeping track of relationships as links, to form a graph.